# Comment apprendre le langage oral de tous les jours ?

Tags: oral

J'apprends le français hors de France. J'ai la chance de bien comprendre la langue non-familière.  Mais parfois, lorsque j’écoute des chansons ou regarde des films, j’ai des difficultés à comprendre.  Par exemple, « je suis venue te voir » (prononcé « [ʃɥi] v'nu t'voir »), « parce que » (« parsk »), « je ne sais pas » (« je n’sais pas »)…

Est-ce que vous pouvez me recommander une méthode ou un ouvrage qui m’aiderait à apprendre la langue orale familière ? Qui emploie si possible l’alphabet phonétique international (API ou IPA).

Comment: Comme c'est un registre oral, peu de chance de trouver ça avec la prononciation; surtout que ça varie en fonction de la région.

Comment: Je pense que justement, le meilleur moyen de s'habituer est les films et les chansons en français (avec sous-titres si c'est trop difficile). Les français parlent comme ça, il vaut mieux s'habituer avant d'en avoir vraiment besoin.

Comment: Oui, seule l'écoute et la pratique te permettront de connaitre ce niveau de langue qui par définition n'est presque pas documenté. D'ailleurs, si tu ne sais pas par où commencer, ton titre m'a fait penser à un album (punk-rock, pour simplifier) du groupe *Les Amis d'ta femme*, dont le titre (inoubliable) est : *Si t'en r'veux, y'en r'n'as!*.

Answer (score 7):

Je pense que le meilleur moyen comme dit dans les commentaires est de regarder des films/séries sous-titrés (c'est comme ça que j'ai appris l'anglais) pour faire facilement le lien entre oral et écrit. Mais le problème est que pour qu'un film soit bon, il faut travailler les dialogues (et travailler les paroles en musique). Ainsi, toutes les œuvres ne sont pas forcément bonnes pour travailler l'oral, il faut chercher les dialogues les plus naturels.

Je ne suis pas un grand cinéaste, j'invite donc ceux qui ont des idées à compléter ma réponse. Je pense que des séries Épiques/Réalistes telles que Kaamelott ou Hero Corp peuvent être un bon moyen de voir le parler moins formel.
(Voir opensubtitles.org/fr pour les sous-titres, tous types confondus)

Et sans se limiter aux films/séries, je pense aussi que les vidéos type podcast sur youtube sont un bon moyen. Sans débattre de la qualité de l'humour, ces vidéos courtes annoncent leur sujet dès le titre, et cela permet de facilement s'y retrouver (niveau vocabulaire et expressions). (Liens: [Cyprien](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyWqModMQlbIo8274Wh_ZsQ), [Norman](https://www.youtube.com/user/NormanFaitDesVideos) pour citer les plus connus, il y en a plein d'autres).

Je pense aussi à [Naheulbeuk](http://www.penofchaos.com/warham/donjon.htm), c'est assez spécial mais cela correspond à mon critère de dialogues naturels.

Et pour finir, je pense aussi que regarder des spectacles comiques est une bonne idée, mais par contre trouver des sous-titres sera plus difficile si on ne passe pas par l'achat du DVD.

Je pense avoir fait le tour des éléments simples que je connaissais, je sais qu'il y a aussi des œuvres qui contextualisent des milieux spécifiques, mais c'est souvent subjectif. L'autre solution est d'écouter des français parler entre eux dans une situation banale (je pense au vocal d'un jeu en ligne par exemple).

Answer (score 1):

C'est en anglais, mais moi, j'aime bien *The Sounds of French: An Introduction* de Bernard Tranel pour la phonologie française courante (c'est descriptif, pas prescriptif), par exemple il décrit bien les assimilations et les e muets. Bien sur, il utilise l'IPA. Il décrit bien aussi les différences entre les dialectes principaux de France, mais il n'y a pas beaucoup des autres dialectes.

Je n'ai pas d'avis pour vous sur les autres partes de la langue courante. Bien sur que l'on peut utiliser cette page web pour une telle question !